# char array assignment using two indexes added together

Tags: c

So here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
char name[62],first[31],last[31];
int i, j;

printf("What is your first name? ");
scanf("%[^\n]", first);
fflush(stdin);
printf("What is your last name? ");
scanf("%[^\n]", last);
fflush(stdin);


for (i=0; first[i]!='\0' ; i++)
    name[i]=first[i];

name[i]=' '; // for loop ends before null so insert space after last char
i++;

for (j=0; last[j]!='\0'; j++)
    name[i+j]=last[i+j];

name[i+j]='\0'; // ends before null so input null

printf("%s", name);


}
```

So I compile it and I can get the first name outputted from name, but it stops there. I checked the solution and the correct way to do it is to use:

```
    for (j=0; last[j]!='\0'; j++, i++)
        name[i]=last[j];

    name[i]='\0'; // ends before null so input null
    printf("%s", name);
```

it makes sense to do it that way, but I was wondering if my original method could work. It is an exercise to imitate strcpy and strcat so I know those two ways are faster.

Comment: You don't need the `"%["` format when reading the names, the normal string `"%s"` code will work fine. Also note that in standard C `fflush(stdin)` is undefined. And it's not needed as the `"%s"` skip leading whitespace anyway. I recommend you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: `scanf("%30[^\n]%*c", first);` , Put a limit on the number of input characters.,

Comment: I use the "%[" instead of %s in case users enter a space in their name such as first: John Stevens last: Wilson, since it will get cut off after 'n' in John. Thanks for the recommendation article it was informative. How exactly does "%30[^\n]%*c" work specifically "%*c"? I was unable to find anything online through google about it, but it does make the output much more favorable.

Comment: @Khrono scanf("%30[^\n]%*",first) means only first 30 characters including spaces are considered and stored on address specified by next parameter that is address of array first, and %* means rest of the input will be just ignored. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) is a good stuff about scanf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one

```
for (j=0; last[j]!='\0'; j++)
    name[i+j]=last[i+j];
```

should read

```
for (j=0; last[j]!='\0'; j++)
    name[i+j]=last[j];
```

because `i` is the offset into the `name` array where you want to start writing the last name, and `j` counts the characters of the last name.

That said, there are some other major issues with your code (try entering a name part with more than 31 characters and you'll see...)

Comment: Thank you for that. I realize now that my indexing for last was off. Is there a recommended length instead of 31? I thought most names wouldn't go longer than that.

Comment: @user3345423 No, but you should limit the number of characters which can be read. Have a look at `fgets()`, for example.